# How to change Dojo TabContainer behaviour to simply open an external link instead of showing a ContentPane?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dojo, tabs, tabcontainer

I am working with a `TabContainer` having several different `ContentPane` children. Each of them is equipped with a `href` param to fetch external AJAX content shown when a tab is being selected:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var tc_nav = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
        style: 'width: 98%;',
        doLayout: false
    }, 'tc_nav');

    var cp1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        title: 'Test 1',
        href: 'ajax?test1',
        style: 'padding: 10px;',
        selected: true
    });

    dojo.connect(cp1, 'onShow', function() {
        cp1.refresh();
    });

    /*
     * ...
     */

    tc_nav.addChild(cp1);

    /*
     * ...
     */

    tc_nav.startup();
});
```

Now I want to integrate a tab among the others which should be different in its behaviour: Instead of loading content into a `ContentPane` the tab should follow a simple link in the same window (like a `<a href="http://www.google.com/">Link</a>`), leaving the page containing the js/dojo app. I didn't find any satisfying solution yet, nor a dojo widget matching this requirement. What would be the best approach?

As an unpleasant workaround I created an overridden `onShow` event firing a `window.location.href = '...';`:

```
var cp2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
    title: 'Test 2',
    style: 'padding: 10px;'
});

dojo.connect(cp2, 'onShow', function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
});
```

An annoying disadvantage of this workaround is the fact the `ContentPane` is loaded first and afterwards the `window.location.href` is set, which leads to a quite peculiar lazy reload effect and consequently to a bad user experience. I would like to avoid this intermediate step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround to meet the above mentioned requirements is to override the `onClick` event of the `ContentPane`'s `controlButton`:

```
/*
 * ...
 */

var cp2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
    title: 'Test 2',
    style: 'padding: 10px;'
});

/*
 * ...
 */

tc_nav.addChild(cp2);

/*
 * ...
 */

tc_nav.startup();

/*
 * ...
 */

cp2.controlButton.onClick = function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
};
```

Please note not to attach another function to the `onClick` event (e. g. by `dojo.connect(cp2.controlButton, 'onClick', function() { /* ... */ });`), but rather to override it, otherwise the `ContentPane`'s content would be called up first.

Please note further the `TabContainer`'s `startup()` function has to be invoked first to make the `controlButton` object accessible.

Answer (score 0):

ContentPanes are not actually iframes, so setting window.location.href would change the url of your entire page (dojo app) not just the ContentPane.  Have you tried something like this:

```
cp2.set('href', 'http://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. I actually **want** to change the url of my entire page. The way you suggested would just XHR-load the contents of http://www.google.com/ into my `ContentPane` and present it iframe-like, which is the conventional behaviour of a `TabContainer`.

Comment: Yup, I misunderstood.  How would you reload the entire page but leave your app in place?

Comment: I don't want to leave my app in place, I just want to reload the entire page with certain url parameters.